# AutoCAD .NET Selection set filter: What types of entities can be add to the filter to be selected?

Tags: c#, autocad, autocad-plugin

1. I am using selection set filter to select certain types of entities in a drawing. It happened to me that I can add Line, Circle, Ellipse... to my filter for the types of entities to be selected. However, I can not add Polyline to the filter.
   Why is that? What is the types of entities I can add to a selection set filter and what types I can not?
2. The DfxCode.Start only specify the object to instantiate a TypedValue is a string. How will AutoCAD .net recognize the string to decide which type of entities to add to the selection set? Is there a pre-defined series of string value for this conversion/ recognition?

P/s: the .net dev guide only shows that I can add entity to selection set, not much else. Any explanation or suggestion is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the DXF Entities in a `SelectionFilter` listed at http://help.autodesk.com/view/ACD/2018/ENU/?guid=GUID-7D07C886-FD1D-4A0C-A7AB-B4D21F18E484 To find that link, or similar, web-search for "dxf entities 2018" or whatever year-version of AutoCAD you are looking for.

This is a pretty good example of how to set a filter: http://through-the-interface.typepad.com/through_the_interface/2008/07/conditional-sel.html.  Search for "Autocad c# selection set filter" for similar.

Polylines: there are `POLYLINE` & `LWPOLYLINE` in dxf. In AutoCAD there are 2d & 3d Polylines as well as lightweight ones.

See the [AutoCAD Tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/autocad/info) for more dev resources

Answer (score 0):

Use LWPOLYLINE

Example:
'' Create a TypedValue array to define the filter criteria
Dim acTypValAr(0) As TypedValue
acTypValAr.SetValue(New TypedValue(DxfCode.Start, "LWPOLYLINE"), 0)